# Problema com Array Multidimensional em Python

Tags: python, array, processamento-de-imagens, array-multidimensional

Basicamente o meu algoritmo importa todas as fotos que eu tenho dentro de um diretório (dataset_train), salvando estas fotos no vetor X e o nome da pasta em que ela se encontrava no vetor Y.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("dataset_train"):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    for file in files:
        imagem_nome = root + '/' + file
        imagem = cv2.imread(imagem_nome, 0)
        x.append(imagem)
        y.append(path[1])

print('Imagens para treinamento lidas:', len(x))


(x_train, y_train) = (np.asarray(x), y)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_train[0].shape)
```

**Saída:**

```
Imagens para treinamento lidas: 11957

(11957,)

(250, 250)
```

Eu estou usando como base o algoritmo CNN MNIST, em que ele possui 60000 imagens, 28x28 pixels.  Neste algoritmo quando eu uso `shape()`  no vetor de treinamento ele retorna `(60000, 28, 28)`. Mas quando eu faço isso no meu ele retorna apenas `(11957,)`, eu preciso que ele retorne `(11957,250, 250)`. Meu dataset são fotos de 250x250 pixels.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso, por favor? Sou novato em Python :(

Comment: Engraçado que eu tentei fazer em um dataset menor e este meu código deu certo. Mas seu eu tento fazer neste dataset maior da esse problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na minha experiência, isso occore quando as matrizes em `x` possuem diferentes tamanhos, e assim a conversão para vetor do `numpy` agrupa apenas a primeira dimensão.
Entre as razões que podem ter causado este problema, estão:

- **Carregamento de arquivos inválidos** - pode haver algum arquivo que não é imagem no seu diretório, de modo que tenta-se usar o `cv2.imread` para lê-lo. De acordo com a documentação, a função `cv.read` não dispara exceções quando lê arquivos inválidos, mas sim retorna `None`<sup>[*]</sup>
- **Imagens com dimensões diferentes** - havendo imagens de resoluções distintas, as matrizes lidas também terão tamanhos distintos

### Sugestões

Para descobrir se esse problema ocorre, deve ser suficiente

- Verificar se nenhuma imagem lida por `cv2.imread` retorna `None`. Isso pode ser feito trocando o conteúdo do `if` interno para

```py
imagem_nome = root + '/' + file
imagem = cv2.imread(imagem_nome, 0)
if imagem is None:
    print("Imagem inválida:", file)
else:
    x.append(imagem)
    y.append(path[1])
```

- Criar um conjunto (tipo `set`) com as dimensões de todas as imagens. 
  Isso pode ser feito usando

```
print({img.shape() for img in x})
```

logo após o laço `for`.

---

<sup>[*] - Informação na página 21 do [manual de opencv-python](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/opencv-python-tutroals/latest/opencv-python-tutroals.pdf), em inglês</sup>

Comment: Descobri o problema, tinha um arquivo de texto em uma das pastas do dataset, por conta disso dava esse problema que você disse sobre as dimensões. Agora ta funcionando. Obrigado!